# Core Data - Relationship is not saving in a loop

Tags: swift, core-data

I've created a function to save a CoreData entity. The function is called by a loop within another function. The entity is saved, but the relationship is saved only once. Any idea why?

```
func saveEpisode(podcast:Podcast, feedEpisode:FeedEpisode) -> Bool {

    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return  false}
    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let newEpisode = Episode.init(entity: NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Episode", in:managedContext)!, insertInto: managedContext)

    newEpisode.setValue(feedEpisode.title, forKey: "title")
    newEpisode.setValue(podcast, forKey: "episodePodcast")


    do {
        try managedContext.save()
        return true
              
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        return false
    }


}
```

The function that's calling this one:

```
func saveNewFeedEpisodes(podcast: Podcast, feedEpisodes:[FeedEpisode]) {

    
    for feedEpisode in feedEpisodes {
        var episodeMatch = false
        
        for localEpisode in self.localEpisodes {
            
            _ = self.saveEpisode(podcast:podcast, feedEpisode:feedEpisode)
        
        }
        
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `for localEpisode in self.localEpisodes`, this loop looks strange. First of all you use `self.localEpisodes` which you haven't explained what it is in your question and then you don't use the elements in the loop when calling `saveEpisode` so the loop seem unnecessary (or the outer loop is not needed or there is something you have forgotten to explain in your question)

Comment: A bit off-topic but there is no need to use `setValue(forKey)` when you can use the entity directly, `newEpisode.title = feedEpisode.title` for instance, more swifty and the compiler will tell you directly if you spell a property wrong